# NDepend CQL queries returning N/A for LOC

Tags: ndepend, cql

Using the the following CQL query:

```
SELECT  NAMESPACES WHERE NameLike "Test$" ORDER BY NbLinesOfCode DESC
```

I am getting some results that show "N/A" instead of a number for NbLinesOfCode.  Anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Note: I tried changing NbLinesOfCode to NbILInstructions, and none of the result records showed N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two things here:

- If both [NbLinesOfCode](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfCode) and [NbILInstructions](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbILInstructions) shows N/A, it means that the namespace doesnt have any code and contains only types without code (like interfaces, delegates or enumerations)
- If only [NbLinesOfCode](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbLinesOfCode) shows N/A but [NbILInstructions](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx#NbILInstructions) shows something, then it means NDepend cannot have access to the assemblies PDB. More information in: [Understanding NDepend Analysis Inputs](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Inputs.aspx)

Comment: Patrick, thank you for your response.  My solution has 35 projects, and in the "error list" of NDepend I see there are 5 warnings that say that 5 PDB's are corrupted, and it correlates perfectly with the NA results that I see.  Unfortunately I have no idea what is wrong with the PDB's - they are being generated directly by Visual Studio's build and I have verified that they are up to date.

Comment: I should add that I am able to debug the assemblies that NDepend has labelled corrupt.  I guess I need to somehow determine if problem is within NDepend, VS/MS build, or my source code.

Comment: Concerning the PDBs corrupted, do they get instrumented somehow (profile, or VSTS tooling?). What do these 5 assemblies differentiate from the others?